# I want a two word answer - How well do you know your idioms?

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

Here's something a bit different from my usual puzzles... How well do you know your idioms?

Solve each of the clues below and from them give me one two word answer for the whole puzzle - with explanations obviously :)

> Lack the tools for playing Craps
>
> Not where a train should be perhaps
>
> Attractive to an infant fowl
>
> An iffy cure from beasts that howl
>
> Hungry for what's on your head?
>
> Higher than white condiment
>
> Rotating common furnishing
>
> Squashed into house of seed-like thing
>
> An egg found in a likely place
>
> Retrieve your sheep with longer face

Comment: Does each line have a two word answer or is a two word answer required after the clues are solved?

Comment: One two-word answer for the whole puzzle @JamesCoyle :)  Edited to try and clarify,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

'Borrowing' some answers from Jassen and JamesCoyle:

```
Lack the tools for playing Craps
```

> **N**o Dice - craps is a dice game, the idiom means 'no chance'

```
No where a train should be perhaps
```

> **O**ff the rails/**O**ff track

```
Attractive to an infant fowl
```

> **C**hick magnet

```
An iffy cure from beasts that howl
```

> **H**air of the dog

```
Hungry for what's on your head?
```

> <strike>I'll</strike> **E**at my hat - used as a bet of sorts against something unlikely happening (rarely results in the consumption of headwear)

```
Higher than white condiment
```

> **A**bove the salt? Not one I'd heard before - high in status, essentially, dating back to when salt was a precious commodity and sat in the middle of the table. Sitting towards the top of the table indicates importance

```
Rotating common furnishing
```

> **T**ables have turned

```
Squashed into house of seed-like thing
```

> **I**n a nutshell

```
An egg found in a likely place
```

> **N**est egg - refers to saved/invested money

```
Retrieve your sheep with longer face
```

> **G**et your goat

Then taking the first letter of each ('Hungry for what's on your head' gives an 'E' here) we get:

> No cheating

Comment: Getting there. +1

Comment: @BrentHackers Got there, I think. Interesting puzzle!

Comment: You do got it!  Well done.

Comment: I knew it was the first letters! Didn't realize I messed up the order of them in mine so no wonder I was getting nonsense. Well done!

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what the final solution is yet but here are the clues:

```
Lack the tools for playing Craps
```

> No Dice

```
No where a train should be perhaps
```

> Off the rails

```
Attractive to an infant fowl
```

> Chick magnet

```
An iffy cure from beasts that howl
```

> Hair of the dog

```
Hungry for what's on your head?
```

> Eat my hat

```
Higher than white condiment
```

> Above the salt

```
Rotating common furnishing
```

> Tables have turned

```
Squashed into house of seed-like thing
```

> In a nutshell

```
An egg found in a likely place
```

> Nest egg

```
Retrieve your sheep with longer face
```

> <s>A wolf in sheep's clothing</s> Get your goat

Edited to fix the order.

Answer (score 4):

The solution

> No cheating

by taking the first letter of each answer:

```
Lack the tools for playing Craps
```

> No dice

```
No where a train should be perhaps
```

> Off the rails

```
Attractive to an infant fowl
```

> Chick magnet

```
An iffy cure from beasts that howl
```

> Hair of the dog

```
Hungry for what's on your head?
```

> Eat my hat

```
Higher than white condiment
```

> Above the salt

Thanks James Coyle (this is not an idiom I have heard before)

```
Rotating common furnishing
```

> Turn the tables

```
Squashed into house of seed-like thing
```

> In a nutshell

```
An egg found in a likely place
```

> Nest egg

```
Retrieve your sheep with longer face
```

> Get your goat

Thanks Engineer Toast

Comment: The word count is for the final answer @Jasen - not the answer to each clue.  Edited my question to try and clarify that a bit.  +1